# Changing the date format from mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I need to change the date format from `2015-04-08` to `08-APR-2015`.
It is coming from grails gsp front end.
Before calling oracle package I need to change the format in java.
How to do it.

Comment: Do you want to format date at client side (javascript) or server side (java)? because you mentioned java in your question while tagged javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use SimpleDateFormat in changing date formats. Try this:

```
String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
String NEW_FORMAT = "dd-MMM-yyyy";

String oldDateString = "2015-04-08";
String newDateString;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT);
Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);
sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
newDateString = sdf.format(d);
```

Comment: did the rtrick with sdf.applyPattern(NEW_FORMAT). I was missing this line.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**You mentioned Java in your answer but you tagged JavaScript I've edited your question to show the Java tag. This is a JavaScript soution.**

Assuming **str** is you input:

```
str.split('-').forEach(function(a,i,b){
    result += i===0?(b[2]+'-'):i===1?(((new Date(str)).toUTCString()).split(' ')[2]+'-').toUpperCase():a[0];
});
```

Comment: It is in server side.Done.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Ok I already see and answer but still want to add one.I am not sure you want JS or Java solution. You can this using Javascript or Java. Below are both ways:
**Javascript**

```
var c = new Date('2015-04-08');
locale = "en-us" 
function formatDate(d)
 {
    var month = d.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
    var day = d.getDate();
    day = day + "";
    if (day.length == 1)
     {
     day = "0" + day;
      }
      return day + '-' + month +'-' + d.getFullYear();
  }
```

And if you want same in Java you do below..
**Java**

```
String myDateString = "2015-04-08";
String reqDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(myDateString);
```

Better if done in Java looks more simpler and reliable..

Comment: Yes,done.Was able to do in server side.I was missing some syntax